# How can I read heterogeneous binary data from a mmap'd file using boost?

Tags: c++, boost, ifstream, mmap

I have built a little test app to read binary data from a file using `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source`.

Unfortunately I'm getting garbage out - so am clearly not reading the data correctly.

My assumption was that I could just cast the `data()` pointer to whatever type I am expecting, but I'm supposing that is incorrect.

```
const char* data = file.data();
uint64_t f1 = (uint64_t)*data;  // incorrect
```

**Proof:**

I built another test app using `std::ifstream` to verify the data, and that works as expected.

**Question:**

How do I read heterogeneous binary data from `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source`?

### Examples:

Both the working `ifstream` and broken `boost` test apps are below.

**Working example of reading binary data with `std::ifstream`:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

template<typename T>
void read(std::ifstream& ifs, T& data)
{
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof(T));
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("/tmp/data", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    uint64_t f1;
    int32_t  f2
    double   f3;

    while(1)
    {
        read(ifs, f1);
        read(ifs, f2);
        read(ifs, f3);

        if (ifs.eof())
            break;

        std::cout << f1 << ' ' << f2 << ' ' << f3 << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output (correct):**

> ```
> 1463071170459690752 400 90.08
> 1463071170504337152 400 90.08
> 1463071170561888256 300 90.08
> 1463071170561923328 400 90.08
> 1463071170561973760 500 90.08
> ```

**Broken example of reading binary data with `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source`:**

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source file;
    file.open("/tmp/data");

    int         size = file.size();
    const char* data = file.data();

    uint64_t    f1;
    int32_t     f2
    double      f3;

    while (size > 0)
    {
        f1 = (uint64_t)*data; data += sizeof(uint64_t); size -= sizeof(uint64_t);
        f2 = (int32_t)*data;  data += sizeof(int32_t);  size -= sizeof(int32_t);
        f3 = (double)*data;   data += sizeof(double);   size -= sizeof(double);

        std::cout << f1 << ' ' << f2 << ' ' << f3 << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output (incorrect):**

> ```
> 0 -112 -123
> 0 -112 -123
> 0 44 -123
> 0 -112 -123
> 0 -12 -123
> ```

Comment: Scan (my) SO answers for Boost Interprocess `managed_mapped_file` for lots of inspiration I'd recommend

Comment: @sehe, despite the title, this question actually has very little to do with boost.interprocess :)

Comment: @SergeyA I know this. I don't think i said anything to that effect. I just made a related recommendation.

Comment: @sehe - great inspiration there - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing your conversions wrong. I will give you one example, you can fix the rest.

```
f1 = (uint64_t)*data;
```

This dereferences `char*` - giving you a single 1-byte value - and than converts this one-byte value to 64bit int! Defintely not you want to do. Instead, you need this:

```
f1 = *(uint64_t*)data;
```

And since I do prefer explicits, better yet,

```
f1 = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(data);
```

Comment: I believe your `reinterpret_cast` will need to keep the `const` qualifier. `f1 = *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(data);`